# Android - Espresso How to test an view after clicked and moved to another Activity

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

I'm beginner of Espresso UI Testing. I have an issue, I have found solution but I'm not know how to do that correctly :((

**Problem:**
I have 2 ImageView, when I click on once will change drawable of it and start an Activity. I want to check drawable after click does correct?

**My code**

```
// In Main Activity
val imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.iv_button1)
imageView1.setOnClickListener {
    imageView1.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.image1))
    startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, OtherAcitivy1::class.java))
}
val imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.iv_button2)
imageView2.setOnClickListener {
    imageView2.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.image2))
    startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, OtherAcitivy2::class.java))
}

// In Android Test Class
...After run activiy
@Test
fun checkClickImageView1() {
    onView(withId(R.id.iv_button1)).perform(click())

    // In here, I want to check the imageview has displayed drawable correctly
    onView(withId(R.id.iv_button1)).check(withDrawableMatcher(R.drawable.image1))
}
```

But, It throw an exception is could not found view with `R.id.iv_button1`.

I think, because I start `OtherActivty2` on action click so it could not found view with that `id` from root view of `OtherActivty2`

Have any solution can help me check drawable of ImageView in this case?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [espresso intents](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents#java)

This way you capture that your app is going to open the other activity and respond with a result. Then, as the activity you are has not changed you can check the drawable there.

The code in your case should be something like:

```
@Test
fun checkClickImageView1() {
    val result = Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null)
    // Set up result stubbing when an intent sent to "OtherAcitivy2" is seen.
    intending(hasComponent(OtherAcitivy2::class.java.name)).respondWith(result)
    onView(withId(R.id.iv_button1)).perform(click())

    onView(withId(R.id.iv_button1)).check(withDrawableMatcher(R.drawable.image1))
}
```

don't forget to add the `espresso-intents` dependencies in your `build.gradle` file.